# Identifying different coin values from an image using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing, image-segmentation

I'm trying to identify the number of matches and coins of each value in a picture using MATLAB.
Here is the starting picture, with matches and 4 different coin values. 
(5 small silver, 2 small gold, 2 big silver, 4 big gold coins)
[image]

The output:
[image]

Here's the code:

```
close all;
img = (imread('C:\Users\Torstein\Jottacloud\Skole\Visu\Prosjekt\sample_images\sample2.jpg'));
img_gray = rgb2gray(img);

% Filter image for easier edge detection
m = 12;
n = 12;
img_filter = imfilter(img_gray, fspecial('average', [m n]));
%figure, imshow(f), title('f')

% Edge detection
[~, threshold] = edge(img_filter, 'canny');
fudgeFactor = 1.5;
img_edge = edge(img_filter, 'canny', threshold * fudgeFactor);
figure, imshow(img_edge), title('edge detection')

% Dilate image to make the coin edges complete without holes
se_disk = strel('disk',4);
se_line1 = strel('line',3,100);
se_line2 = strel('line',3,100);
img_dilated = imdilate(img_edge, se_disk);
img_dilated = imdilate(img_dilated, [se_line1 se_line2]);
figure, imshow(img_dilated), title('dilate')

% Remove small objects (noise) and fill complete objects
img_clearborder = imclearborder(img_dilated, 4);
%figure, imshow(BWclear), title('cleared border image');
img_fill = imfill(img_clearborder, 'holes');
figure, imshow(img_fill), title('fill holes')

% Erode image to make a clear cut between objects
se_diamond = strel('diamond',2);
img_erode = imerode(img_fill,se_diamond);
for k=1:3
    img_erode = imerode(img_erode,se_diamond);
end
img_nosmall = bwareaopen(img_erode,300);
figure, imshow(img_nosmall), title('erode')

[B, L] = bwboundaries(img_nosmall);
figure, imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5])), title('boundaries')
hold on
for k = 1:length(B)
  boundary = B{k};
  plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
end

stats = regionprops(L,img(:,:,1),...
    'Area','Centroid','Orientation','EquivDiameter','MeanIntensity');
threshold = 0.80; % For differentiating coins from matches based on an objects circularity

coinCentroids = [];
coinIntensities = [];
matchCentroids = [];
matchAngles = [];
coinRatios = [];

for k = 1:length(B)
    boundary = B{k};
    delta_sq = diff(boundary).^2;
    perimeter = sum(sqrt(sum(delta_sq,2)));
    area = stats(k).Area;
    metric = 4*pi*area/perimeter^2;
    metric_string = sprintf('%2.2f',metric);
    angle_string = sprintf('%2.2f',stats(k).Orientation);
    centroid = stats(k).Centroid;
    if metric > threshold
        % Object is round, therefore a coin
        coinCentroids = [coinCentroids; centroid];
        coinIntensities = [coinIntensities; stats(k).MeanIntensity];
        coinRatios = [coinRatios; stats(k).EquivDiameter/area];
    else
        % Object is a match
        angle = stats(k).Orientation;
        matchCentroids = [matchCentroids; centroid];
        matchAngles = [matchAngles; angle];
    end

    plot(centroid(1),centroid(2),'ko');
%     text(boundary(1,2)-35,boundary(1,1)+13,angle_string,'Color','y',...
%       'FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold');

end
```

As you can see, I have identified which objects are coins and which objects are matches.
But, I have big trouble identifying what value the coins have.

For example, Area/diameter of the coins gives the following results. I can't see any clear way to distinguish the different types of coins based solely on this data; the numbers are just too close.

> ```
> 0.0041
> 0.0042
> 0.0043
> 0.0043
> 0.0044
> 0.0045
> 0.0048
> 0.0048
> 0.0053
> 0.0054
> 0.0055
> 0.0055
> 0.0056
> ```

I tried getting the average color intensity from the starting picture of each coin too, but this did not help me separate the silver colored coins from the gold colored coins.

Mean intensity from the Red channel gives no information that there are 6 gold colored coins and 6 silver colored coins.

```
  105.0104
  105.4408
  107.9070
  112.4762
  116.3412
  127.3481
  132.1418
  137.9697
  149.6601
  159.2506
  167.6910
  181.1673
  215.0395
```

**Question: How can I identify the different coin values?**

(Asked how to separate two joined objects here: [Separate two overlapping circles in an image using MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906928/separate-two-overlapping-circles-in-an-image-using-matlab) )

Thanks

Comment: I cannot see the pictures. Error 403.

Comment: Please update your links with the proper images.

Comment: Added new links, thanks

Comment: try `regionprops` with property `'Image'` should give you a nice separation

Comment: @tsom nicely done. this is a very good question - showing a lot of effort on your part and progress.

Comment: @tsom try looking at the `'Eccentricity'` property of the regions.

Comment: @tos another quantity that might be of help is the ratio between the diameter and the area of each object.

Comment: You are very close so I won't provide an answer.  Carrying on with what Shai was talking about, check this post:  http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/85363#answer_94853 . There is a nice formula that calculates the circularity of an object.  If the value is closer to 1, it's closer to a circle while it being smaller than 1 less resembles a circle.  Use `regionprops` with the parameters in the formula to calculate the circularity then threshold using something like `0.5` to extract out the circular objects. The post also exclaims to use eccentricity carefully, if you decide to use it

Comment: I have no problem differentiating the coins from the matches, however I can't figure out how to seperate the different coin values from another. I have tried area, color intensity of the different RGB-channels from the starting picture, but no luck - the numbers are just too close to each others. Any tips?

Comment: @Shai How do I use `regionprops` with `'Image'` to seperate objects? I can't find any examples online and I don't understand the documentation very limited.

Comment: @tsom work in debug mode and give it a try.

Comment: @tsom BTW, your question became quite lengthy. Why don;t you break it into sub-tasks, each in a different question. You may consider answering your own questions - for the sub tasks you alreay figured out. You can link the questions to each other so one can see the whole process end-to-end?

Comment: Removed unnecessary information and made the questions clearer.

Comment: @tsom I still strongly feel you should split into several questions: First question given image identify coins vs matches - this one you can answer yourself using the information in comments. Second question how to better separate objects, for this you better give input image and current mask. Third question how to identify the different coins in the image.

Comment: @tsom - Regarding the non-uniform illumination - are you familiar with [MATLAB's example](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/examples/correcting-nonuniform-illumination.html)?

Comment: @Dev-iL Yes - the filters I use produce better results than the code in the example. But this is not really the problem either - GIVEN that I know where a coin is, how can I figure out what value it is?

Comment: Asked how to separate joined objects [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26906928/separate-two-overlapping-circles-in-an-image-using-matlab). Now this thread only deals with how to identify the different coin-types.

Comment: Is it acceptable to use the holes in the coins as a parameter to determine the value? I mean - let's say you know which coins contain a hole, so you first categorize the coins by the existence of a hole and further refine by area\diameter - this may be enough. To find the inner holes you can use a Hough transform looking for specific radii (I believe that the radius of the holes is ~5px)...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, `regionprops 'BoundingBox'`, I cut out a picture of the coin from the starting picture using `imcrop` and the BoundingBox for the identified coin.

Then, using `imfindcircles` I can detect the holes in the silver-colored coins. At last, I identify the coin value using the area of the coin.

Final code:

```
close all;
img = (imread('C:\Users\Torstein\Jottacloud\Skole\Visu\Prosjekt\sample_images\sample1.jpg'));
%figure, imshow(img);
img_gray = rgb2gray(img);

% img_hsv = rgb2hsv(img); 
% imgv = img_hsv(:,:,3);
% [Gx, Gy] = imgradientxy(imgv);
% [Gmag, Gdir] = imgradient(Gx, Gy);
% Gmag could be useful

% Filter image for easier edge detection
m = 12;
n = 12;
img_filter = imfilter(img_gray, fspecial('average', [m n]));
%figure, imshow(f), title('f')

% Edge detection
[~, threshold] = edge(img_filter, 'canny');
fudgeFactor = 1.5;
img_edge = edge(img_filter, 'canny', threshold * fudgeFactor);
%figure, imshow(img_edge), title('edge detection')

% Dilate image to make the coin edges complete without holes
se_disk = strel('disk',4);
se_line1 = strel('line',3,100);
se_line2 = strel('line',3,100);
img_dilated = imdilate(img_edge, se_disk);
img_dilated = imdilate(img_dilated, [se_line1 se_line2]);
%figure, imshow(img_dilated), title('dilate')

% Remove stuff touching the image border and fill complete objects
img_clearborder = imclearborder(img_dilated, 4);
%figure, imshow(BWclear), title('cleared border image');
img_fill = imfill(img_clearborder, 'holes');
%figure, imshow(img_fill), title('fill holes')

% Erode image to make a clear cut between objects
se_diamond = strel('diamond',2);
img_erode = imerode(img_fill,se_diamond);
for k=1:3
    img_erode = imerode(img_erode,se_diamond);
end
img_nosmall = bwareaopen(img_erode,300); % Remove small objects (noise)
%figure, imshow(img_nosmall), title('erode')

[B, L] = bwboundaries(img_nosmall);
%figure, imshow(label2rgb(L, @jet, [.5 .5 .5])), title('boundaries')
% hold on
% for k = 1:length(B)
%   boundary = B{k};
%   plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'w', 'LineWidth', 2)
% end

stats = regionprops(L,img(:,:,1),...
    'Area','Centroid','Orientation','EquivDiameter','Image','BoundingBox');
threshold = 0.80; % For differentiating coins from matches based on an objects circularity

coinCentroids = [];
coinTypes = []; % 0 for Silver, 1 for Gold
coinValues = []; % 1, 5, 10 eller 20 kroning
coinAreas = [];
silverCoinAreas = [];
goldCoinAreas = [];
matchCentroids = [];
matchAngles = [];
radiusRange = [8,40];

for k = 1:length(B)
    boundary = B{k};
    delta_sq = diff(boundary).^2;
    perimeter = sum(sqrt(sum(delta_sq,2)));
    area = stats(k).Area;
    metric = 4*pi*area/perimeter^2;
    metric_string = sprintf('%2.2f',metric);
    angle_string = sprintf('%2.2f',stats(k).Orientation);
    centroid = stats(k).Centroid;
    if metric > threshold
        % Object is round, therefore a coin
        coinValues = [coinValues; 0];
        coinAreas = [coinAreas; area];
        coinCentroids = [coinCentroids; centroid];
        bbox = stats(k).BoundingBox;
        im = imcrop(img,bbox);
        %figure, imshow(im);
        [centers,radii] = imfindcircles(im,radiusRange,'ObjectPolarity','bright');
        %viscircles(centers,radii);
        if length(centers) > 0
            % Coin has a hole, therefore either 1-kroning or 5-kroning
            coinTypes = [coinTypes; 0];
            silverCoinAreas = [silverCoinAreas; area];

        else
            % Coin does not have hole, therefore either 10-kroning or
            % 20-kroning
            coinTypes = [coinTypes; 1];
            goldCoinAreas = [goldCoinAreas; area];
        end

    else
        % Object is a match
        angle = stats(k).Orientation;
        matchCentroids = [matchCentroids; centroid];
        matchAngles = [matchAngles; angle];
    end

    %plot(centroid(1),centroid(2),'ko');
%     text(boundary(1,2)-35,boundary(1,1)+13,angle_string,'Color','y',...
%       'FontSize',14,'FontWeight','bold');

end

goldThreshold = 0.1;
silverThreshold = 0.1;
maxSilver = max(silverCoinAreas);
maxGold = max(goldCoinAreas);
for k=1:length(coinTypes)
    area = coinAreas(k);
    if coinTypes(k) == 0
        if  area >= maxSilver-maxSilver*silverThreshold
            % 5-kroning
            coinValues(k) = 5;
        else
            % 1-kroning
            coinValues(k) = 1;
        end
    else
        if area >= maxGold-maxGold*goldThreshold
            % 20-kroning
            coinValues(k) = 20;
        else
            % 10-kroning
            coinValues(k) = 10;
        end
    end
end

% OUTPUT:
coinCentroids
coinValues
matchCentroids
matchAngles
```

Thanks

Comment: well done! This thread is a nice example of asking a good question and the resulting learning process.